# Redirecting to Index file in virtual host with htaccess when request file not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've set virtual host in my xampp to access my sites.

I created a folder `my-project` in `htdocs` folder and set virtual host as the following,

I edited hosts file in `windows\system32\drivers\etc` folder and added this line:

```
127.0.0.1 my-project.com www.my-project.com
```

After that, I edited file `httpd-vhosts` in `D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` folder and added following code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/my-project"
ServerName my-project.com
ServerAlias www.my-project.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can access my project with the uri `my-project.com/public` and index file is loaded, but the problem comes in `.htaccess` file which I've created under public folder (same folder which contains `index.php` file) with following lines.

```
<IfModule mode_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-project/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now problem is that if I type `my-project/public/somefile.php` and file does not exist then it is not redirecting to `index.php` file under public folder.

Could anyone please advise as to the solution ?

Comment: "Now problem is that if I type `my-project/public/somefile.php` ..." - I assume you meant `my-project.com/public/somefile.php`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/my-project"
> ```
>
> :
>
> ```
> RewriteBase /my-project/public
> ```

If the `DocumentRoot` is set to the `/my-project` directory, then the `RewriteBase` directive should only reference `/public` (it is relative to the document root), not `/my-project/public` (`my-project.com/my-project/public/index.php` is presumably not the intended URL?).

In other words:

```
RewriteBase /public
```

Or, remove the `RewriteBase` directive completely, as it's not required if the `.htaccess` file is actually in the `/public` subdirectory.

Comment: If you've removed the virtual host container (as stated in your question) then presumably it is now falling back to the main server config (or other vHost container?), and the document root is presumably now set to `D:/xampp/htdocs`? So, yes, in this case you would need the `RewriteBase` directive as set in your question.

Comment: Presumably `my-project.com` still resolves correctly - have you added these as additional `ServerAlias` on the main server config? Or simply allowing the server to _default_? However, ideally, you should have separate vHost containers for each project and preferably outside of the main domains document root - unless all these "projects" are closely related.